# UIButton does not clip its imageView when it's highlighted

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, clipping

I want to create an effect where a button's image slides in / out of button rect, the final effect should look like this:

[sliding buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeEXd.png)

So the first one just started it's "transition", the second is half way through and the last one is fully slided out.

To achieve this, I set the button's *clipsToBounds* property to *YES* and then animate button's *imageView*:

```
- (void)setupButtons
{
self.buttonsYOffset = -60.0;
self.buttonsOriginalY = self.twitterButton.imageView.center.y;

self.twitterButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.twitterButton.imageView.center = CGPointMake(self.twitterButton.imageView.center.x, self.buttonsOriginalY + self.buttonsYOffset);
}
```

and:

```
- (void)show
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
    animations:^ {
        self.twitterButton.imageView.alpha = 1.0;
        self.twitterButton.imageView.center = CGPointMake(self.twitterButton.imageView.center.x, self.buttonsOriginalY);
    }
    completion:^(BOOL success) {
    }
 ];
}

- (void)hide
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
     animations:^ {
         self.twitterButton.imageView.center = CGPointMake(self.twitterButton.imageView.center.x, self.buttonsOriginalY + self.buttonsYOffset);
     }
     completion:^(BOOL success) {

     }
 ];
}
```

Everything works fine if I fire this code when button is in "inactive" state (not tapped) - it slides in and out just fine.

The problem starts when I fire *hide()* method immediately after button has been tapped - It does not slide out then - just highlights for a second, and it's image stays in "opened" position for a while, then skips to "closed" position immediately.

It seems that button's imageView is used only when button is in its default inactive state? Can it be easily fixed?

Comment: `UIButton` has different images for different `UIControlState`s. Have you set the images properly for `UIControlStateHighlighted` and possible `UIControlStateSelected`? It also could be the button's internal code to change images across different states is messing with the animation.

Comment: The images are set correctly. It seems like button's `imageView` is used only for default state?